# Establish the identity: tan u(csc u - sin u) = cos u

Tags: trigonometry

I'm struggling to establish the identity below:

$$\tan\,u(\csc\,u - \sin\,u) = \cos\,u$$

I've ended up with:

$${1 - 2\sin\,u  \over \cos\,u}$$

I don't know if this is correct so far, and if it is, where do I go from here?

Comment: use $\tan u = \frac{\sin u}{\cos u}, \csc u = \frac 1{\sin u}$

Comment: Careless algebra I think!  Your $2\sin u$ should be $\sin^2u$ and the rest is then easy.

Answer (score 3):

Original trigonometric identity:
$$\tan u(\csc u− \sin u)=\cos u$$

Note: Remember that $\frac{\sin^2u}{\sin u}$ is the equivalent of $\frac{1}{\sin u}$

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin u}{\cos u}\times \left(\frac{1}{\sin u} - \frac{\sin^2u}{\sin u}\right) & = \cos u\\
\frac{\sin u}{\cos u}\times \frac{1-\sin^2u}{\sin u} & = \cos u\\
\frac{\sin u}{\cos u}\times \frac{\cos^2u}{\sin u} & = \cos u\\
\cos u & = \cos u
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for walking through all of the intermediate steps.

Comment: You can obtain $\sin u$ by typing \sin u between dollar signs.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\sin u$. Multiplying both sides by $\cos u$ yields:
$$
x\left(\frac{1}{x}-x\right)=\cos^2 u.
$$
Distributing the $x$ on the left yields $1-x^2$, which is the same as the right (since $\sin^2 u+\cos^2 u=1$). Done.

Comment: "Multiplying both sides" is assuming what you want to prove.

Comment: You're technically correct, but if you're being pedantic the original problem is ill-posed whenever $\cos u=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan u \left(\csc u -\sin u\right) = \frac{\sin u}{\cos u}\left(\frac 1{\sin  u} - \sin u\right)= \frac{1}{\cos u}\left(1 - \sin^2 u\right) = \cos u$$